# R- Return Constant column value

Tags: r, dataframe

I omitted columns that are constant from a data frame

```
DataNew <- Data[, dataPreparation::whichAreConstant(Data, verbose= FALSE)]
```

However I want a list of unmatched columns with their constant value

I tried this command to get the list of unmatched columns but I want also the columns values

```
setdfiff(Data, DataNew)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, you can just use that list to extract the unmatched columns from `Data`:

```
Data[,setdfiff(Data, DataNew)]
```

And if you just want one occurrence of the value:

```
Data[1,setdfiff(Data, DataNew)]
```

Comment: Actually I want to extract list of unmatched columns between Data and DataNew and return the columns values as well

Comment: The code I gave will return a dataframe of the unmatched columns (names and values, just like the initial df), or for the 2nd part just the first row. Can you edit your post to show what your desired output would look like?

Comment: the output I got from this command is what I was looking for.